# Display data from multiple Columns from a csv file in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I've tried to display data from a csv files with multiple variables on the columns. Here's a little extract from the data (these are pollen concentration in a country over 30 years) :

| Date | Ambrosia | Artemisia | Asteraceae | Alnus | Betula | Ericaceae | Carpinus | Castanea | Quercus | Chenopodium | Cupressaceae | Acer | Fraxinus | Gramineae | Fagus | Juncaceae | Aesculus | Larix | Corylus | Juglans | Umbellifereae | Ulmus | Urtica | Rumex | Populus | Pinaceae | Plantago | Platanus | Salix | Cyperaceae | Filipendula | Sambucus | Tilia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1992-02-27 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 47 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 62 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-02-28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 203 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 98 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-02-29 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 180 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 91 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-03-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 312 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 240 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-03-02 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 164 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 33 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 63 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-03-03 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 64 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1992-03-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 48 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

You can find the whole dataset here : https://data.public.lu/en/datasets/pollen/#resources

So my question  is : I want to display the date on the x axis (a timeline) and the pollen concentration on the y axis. For now, my problem is that I can't find a way to get all the pollen (there are more than 30 pollens in the complete dataset, so it would be stupid to write them all manually on a variable, no ?)

Here's my current code. As you can see, it perfectly works with one pollen (the second column of my csv file, "Ambrosia"). How can I proceed to get all the columns easily and display their results ? Probably with a loop or something like that, but I don't know how...

Thank you in advance for your answers !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test pollen avec code D3 Graph Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pollen concentration in Luxembourg, 1992-2018</h1>
  <!-- Load d3.js-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7.4.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    const svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Read the data
    d3.csv("pollen_tri.csv",
    
    function(d){
      return { Date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.Date), Ambrosia : +d.Ambrosia }
    }).then(data => {
      

      const x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);

      const monAxeX = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(26)

      //ajouter axe au svg
      svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call((monAxeX));
      
      // Add axe y
      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.Ambrosia; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
      svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
      
      svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr('fill', (d,i) => d3.schemeCategory10[i])
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date) })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.Ambrosia) })
      )
    })
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: duplicating code 30 times, or even two times, is not the correct way to do it. However, pay attention to loops: while I'll use loops for manipulating the data, **do not use loops** for creating the D3 visualisation (i.e., appending the elements).

It all starts with the adequate data for the task. In this case, I'll basically *"transpose"* the rows and columns: we'll create a data array in which each object is an species, that object itself containing an array with dates and values. There are several ways to do that, but I personally like using `reduce`:

```js
const csv = `Date,Ambrosia,Artemisia,Asteraceae,Alnus,Betula,Ericaceae,Carpinus,Castanea,Quercus,Chenopodium,Cupressaceae,Acer,Fraxinus,Gramineae,Fagus,Juncaceae,Aesculus,Larix,Corylus,Juglans,Umbellifereae,Ulmus,Urtica,Rumex,Populus,Pinaceae,Plantago,Platanus,Salix,Cyperaceae,Filipendula,Sambucus,Tilia
1992-02-27,0,0,0,47,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,62,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1992-02-28,0,0,0,203,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,98,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1992-02-29,0,0,0,180,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,91,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1992-03-01,0,0,0,312,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1992-03-02,0,0,0,164,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,63,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0
1992-03-03,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0
1992-03-04,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

const keys = data.columns.slice(1);

const aggregatedData = data.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    keys.forEach(key=>{
    const foundKey = acc.find(d=>d.species === key);
    if(foundKey){
    foundKey.values.push({date: curr.Date, value: curr[key]});
    } else {
        acc.push({species:key, values:[]});
    };
  });
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(aggregatedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Now you have an array of 33 objects, each one being an species.

The next steps are trivial: first, you append 33 groups (each one will hold a path, maybe the text with the name of the species, and any other element you like):

```
const g = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(aggregatedData)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

Now, for each group, you append the path, passing the data inside `values` to the line generator:

```
const path = g.append("path")
    .datum(d => d.values)
    //etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, a new problem appears. The code doesn't recognize my values and returns an error : `Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNLNaN`.

Comment: @Crazychicken you need to refactor your code accordingly, specially your scales.